# Are there any solitary species of ant or termite?

Tags: entomology

The social insects consist of the ants, the bees, and the termites, which live in colonies rather than living solitary.

But I've heard that there are some species of bee which are solitary and don't live in colonies.

Are there also any species anywhere of either ants or termites which are solitary?

Comment: Actually, **most** bees are solitary and don't live in colonies. In the UK 90% according to https://www.growwilduk.com/content/everything-you-need-know-about-solitary-bees

Comment: i.e. bumblebees and burrowing sand bees, bees that build small nests, and vespids that have gall nests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not know of any solitary ants, but there are species that form very small colonies.

One such species is [Jerdon's Jumping Ant (*Harpegnathos saltator*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harpegnathos_saltator). They usually live in colonies [smaller than 100 individuals](http://www.pnas.org/content/92/24/10977.full.pdf) and workers may reproduce, so the colony can survive after the queen's death.

Answer (score 3):

No solitary ants have been described by scientific journals. If they had, they would be a famous exception, their ecology and survival strategy would be very interesting, to know how they rear their broods. It is mostly nectar and parasitism that makes Hymenoptera broods easy to manage alone.

*velvet ants* are solitary and resemble ants but they are actually wingless wasps.

*Meranoplus* primitive old world ants are the most likely to have solitary species, and have simpler clades, i.e. no queen, all workers may lay eggs.

*Pristomyrmex punctatus* also has no queen.

Answer (score 1):

Carpenter ants are solitary you will see one queen in a house full of termites and other ants that live in colonies
I have spent 35 years remodeling homes infested with termites and ants the carpenter ants which are huge are never seen tohether
The queen finds termites and other smaller types of ants
She will stuff these other ants and termits into a tunnel made by the wood chewers and lay an egg and seal the tunnel
The larva hatches and eats the food left
Pupates and digs its way out of the tunnel it then either gets pregnant or looks for a mate if male
Eating the infesting ants and termites 
In 35 years of remodeling and construction with many many homes torn apart i have never seen more then 1 carpenter ants at a time
There are smaller black ants people mistake for the larger cousins but ants that actually tunnel in wood are not carpenter ants
Carpenter ants invade their food's tunnels and feed them to the eggs which they abandon after sealing them into thier egg tunnels which were made by the termites or other ants
Ants are canibals by nature and eat other type of ants
Carpenter are no exception to this rule

Answer (score 0):

There are no solitary termites. All the termitoides are social. You can found some clades that have small colonies like Kalotermitidae, but that is it.